# Using fzero: Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'

Tags: matlab, root, equation, zero, symbolic-math

I use matlab for symbolic calculations. After long calculations I've got a function of x, which is the combination of bessel functions and I want to find it's zeros.

For that purpose I use `fzero` function in Matlab. But while it works perfectly for single bessel functions, it wont work for the mine one.
`>> fzero(@(x)besselj(0,x), 3.5)
ans =
    2.4048`

>> fzero(@(x)DELTA_xi, 3.5)
??? Undefined function or method 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'sym'.

Error in ==> fzero at 333
    elseif ~isfinite(fx) || ~isreal(fx)

>> DELTA_xi
besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, x)*bessely(0, x) - besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(0, x)*bessely(1, x) - besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(0, x)*besselk(1, x) + besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, x)*besselk(0, x) - besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(0, x)*bessely(1, x) - besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(1, x)*bessely(0, x) + besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(0, x)*besselj(1, x) + besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(1, x)*besselj(0, x)

Why this happens? How to solve the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've mistaken function handles with symbolic representation.

fzero needs a function handle.

so if you do:

```
DELTA_xi = @(x) besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, x)*bessely(0, x) - besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(0, x)*bessely(1, x) - besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(0, x)*besselk(1, x) + besseli(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besselj(1, x)*besselk(0, x) - besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(0, x)*bessely(1, x) - besselj(1, (3*x)/10)*besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(1, x)*bessely(0, x) + besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(0, x)*besselj(1, x) + besselk(1, (3*x)/10)*bessely(1, (3*x)/10)*besseli(1, x)*besselj(0, x)
fzero(DELTA_xi, 3.5)
```

you get

```
3.8173
```

note that if you want to call a symbolic function, you'll have to do it indirectly:

```
fzero(@(x)eval(DELTA_xi), 3.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rasman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074062/using-fzero-undefined-function-or-method-isfinite-for-input-arguments-of-type/6075664#6075664) already gave you one solution to your problem, but I thought I'd explain in more detail why you were getting your error and give you another possible solution.

First, consider this anonymous function from your code:

```
fcn1 = @(x) besselj(0,x);
```

This function takes one input argument `x` and passes it to the function [BESSELJ](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/besselj.html) to be evaluated and returned as output. [FZERO](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fzero.html) has no problem using this function.

Now consider this other anonymous function from your code, which has as its expression the symbolic equation `DELTA_xi` created using the symbolic variable `'x'`:

```
fcn2 = @(x) DELTA_xi;
```

This function takes an input argument `x`, but what should be done with this input argument? MATLAB doesn't automatically know to connect the input variable `x` to the symbolic variable `'x'` in `DELTA_xi`, so when this function gets evaluated by FZERO it will simply return the symbolic equation `DELTA_xi` (which FZERO is unable to use, as indicated by the error you see).

Using the function [EVAL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/eval.html) like in [Rasman's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6074062/using-fzero-undefined-function-or-method-isfinite-for-input-arguments-of-type/6075664#6075664) will evaluate `DELTA_xi` using the available value for `x` passed from FZERO to the anonymous function, solving your problem. However, another solution is to use the [SUBS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/symbolic/subs.html) function like so:

```
fzero(@(x) subs(DELTA_xi,'x',x), 3.5)
```

Which will substitute the input value `x` for every occurrence of the symbolic variable `'x'` in `DELTA_xi`, *essentially* doing the same thing as EVAL but *explicitly* stating which symbolic variable the input argument replaces. The difference? Note that this will work:

```
fzero(@(y) subs(DELTA_xi,'x',y), 3.5)
```

But this will not:

```
fzero(@(y) eval(DELTA_xi), 3.5)
```

Because the name of the input variable and the symbolic variable don't match.