# Error in MATLAB.Undefined function 'det' for input arguments of type 'embedded.fi'

Tags: matlab, fixed

I have already seen the link [Error using fzero in Matlab: Undefined function or method 'det' for input arguments of type 'function_handle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136050/error-using-fzero-in-matlab-undefined-function-or-method-det-for-input-argume)
But I am unable to solye my problem with this link.I am working with fi object in MATLAB. I have one matrix  T_1 (2 cross 2) which is conevrted into the fi(T_1,1,32,26,fimath), i.e 32 signed binary number and 26 is the positon of binary point. Now when I try to excute the follwing code

```
  T =  mat_G/(mat_sqrt_D)  
  T_1=fi(T./mat_E,1,32,26,fimath);
  multiplier=1/(2*sqrt(det(var_oldS))*abs(det(T_1)));
```

follwing error appears

```
Undefined function 'det' for input arguments of type 'embedded.fi'.
```

So can anyone tell me how can i fix it.

P.S variable var_oldS, mat_G,mat_E, mat_qrt_D has the same fi object properties i.e fi(variable_name,1,32,26,fimath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the documentation for `det`, it says that the input must be single or double. Fixed point is probably not supported. As your matrix is of fixed size 4, it's simple to replace the function:

```
det2=@(M)M(1)*M(4)-M(2)*M(3)
```

Then use det2 instead of det.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  The thing is that I have given just one exaple here. My algorith is desined for the n dimesion so the matrix can go upto n cross n . So according to your suggestion i have to write another function to calulate the deteminant of matrix size n cross n. Is there another way possible. Because I have some timing isuues to. I want a faster algorithm...

Comment: Please describe your full problem. Where is your code executed, in Matlab or on some embedded system? If you run it in matlab, don't use `fi` to increase the performance.

Comment: I am excuting my code right now in MATLAB. But I need to covert it on fixed point. Inspite of using MATLAB fixed point coder app , I am doing it manually . So is there is any other alternative